# Web Forms controls null at runtime. Fixes itself after renaming control id

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Very occasionally I get this bizarre Microsoft bug where a control on a Web Form (with a designer file), is null at runtime.

Renaming the control's ID in the ASPX page always fixes the problem, but nothing else will.

The problem doesn't occur with all controls - just some - and usually a control which I've recently added to the page.

Anyone else seen this one?

Comment: This is not the answer to my problem, but is the answer to a similar problem: http://royaltutorials.com/asp-net-user-control-controls-are-null/
Make sure if you are importing user controls that you are using the Register directive with the Src attribute, not the Assembly attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I saw those kind of things in two separate cases:

1. You set up OutputCache on yours controls - for this you just have to be aware which controls are using OutputCache and even better make this control self-sufficient, so that no external interaction from the page is required.
2. Corresponding designer file is broken for some reason and VisualStudio does not update the IDs correctly - I never had so much time and patience to dig into it.

Comment: Hi thanks, I know about the first issue - that's not occuring here. As for the second explanation, I can see the correctly named control in the designer file. If it wasn't there, the page wouldn't compile anyway because the code behind needs to use the control (which is why I know the control is null). So it could be something else wrong in the designer file, but what that could be I have no idea.

Comment: ok, what i meant was that designer file contains IDs which are used in code behind, but aspx file has updated IDs.

Is there a chance that you copied/pasted your pages/controls or updated their name?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by a control with invalid content in its text. Make sure that you remove all `<`, `>` characters from the values of the control, then test it.